# Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Seeking interrupted. on expo video av React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

I'm trying to implement the setPositionAsync() for changing the position of the video with a slider, it works, but when i change it it gives me hundreds and hundreds of warnings about an `unhandled promise rejection : Error: Seeking interrupted.`
Please help me i'm working with expo

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?